# How to set ext3 partition hidden flag?

Tags: linux, partitioning, ext3

I have a created an ext3 partition and when i tried to set is hidden flag, there seems no effect.

So, how to set the hidden flag of an ext3 partition?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you did to set the flag and what you used to verify that it was/was not hidden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as a "hidden flag" for ext3 partitions. Or for any partition, really; the partition identifier gets changed to something else instead (0x0b -> 0x1b, 0x07 -> 0x17, etc.).

Comment: so, what is the right way to hide an ext3 partition?

Comment: There is no way. Just don't mount it.